# Identificação e marcação de palavras chave de script SQL dentro de um documento Word

Tags: sql, microsoft-word, palavras-reservadas

Estou fazendo um manual de erros do sistema para empresa onde trabalho. Dentro deste manual terá a descrição do erro, assim como sua solução. Muitas das soluções são scripts SQL bem extensos.

Gostaria de saber se é possível marcar (deixar em negrito e outra cor) as palavras chave apenas dentro da área do script, como: SELECT, UPDATE, *, FROM, WHERE.. etc.

Assim como é utilizado em fóruns, o pages do dropbox, etc. Pode ser semelhante a algo que é feito aqui mesmo no stackoverflow, ex:

```
SELECT * FROM teste;
```

Comment: Creio que sua pergunta está fora do escopo do site. Entretanto, sugiro que você não faça isso em Word. Utilize outro tipo de ferramenta de documentação, uma que seja baseada em HTML+CSS. Utilize alguma ferramenta do tipo Wiki (onde trabalho utilizamos o TWiki exatamente para isso que vc está fazendo).

Comment: Inclusive, existe um plugin (pra TWiki) chamado SyntaxHighlight. Ele destaca várias linguagens. Exatamente dessa maneira que você precisa.

Comment: Bom dia Cantoni, porque estaria fora do escopo? Sobre o TWiki, não conhecia a ferramenta e é bem interessante, principalmente de várias pessoas estarem interagindo. Seria algo similar ao trello, ou até mesmo o evernote group?

Comment: Está fora do escopo, pois não trata de programação. A vantagem do TWiki (e de outros tipos de ferramentas colaborativas é essa), várias pessoas podem interagir, mudar o conteúdo, enfim contribuir. Geralmente, documentação tende a desatualizar. O Word potencializa esse problema, pois não é uma ferramenta colaborativa. Precisa ficar copiando o arquivo e enviando para o outro mudar, ou compartilhar numa pasta, não dá certo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que você quer é realce de sintaxe (Syntax highlighting).

Usando o [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) e o plugin **NppExport** você consegue fazer isso.

Primeiro selecione a sintaxe que você vai usar através do menu *Linguagem » S » SQL*.

Escreva o seu código e depois para exportar para o Word vá em *Plugins » NppExport » Copy all formats to clipboard.*

Depois basta colar no Word usando o <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>